# How to connect MongoDb docker container from host?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I'm learning MongoDb and I'm trying to create a simple CRUD with NodeJS. I build the container from this docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123mudar

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123mudar
```

I did the connection instance of two ways:

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:123mudar@localhost:27017/learning_mongo', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });`

`mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/learning_mongo', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true });`

Both didnt work. Hosting these container from Ubuntu and I tried to connect using command line.

**$ mongo**

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2020-12-11T02:17:48.844-0300 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-12-11T02:17:48.844-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Anyone can help me to find out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    container_name: scan-app-backend
    restart: always
    build: ./api
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:21017"

  react-app:
    container_name: scan-app-frontend
    build: ./dashboard
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    stdin_open: true
```

Now you have to change the database URL while passing in the Express server.

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/scans', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB server"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

*I am not sure what's mongo-express*

In your case would be

Docker compose-

The MongoDB server in the image listens on the standard MongoDB port, 27017

```
mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: 123mudar
```

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

module.exports = mongoose
  .connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/learning_mongo', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB server"))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```